# Displaying date consistently, regardless of time zone, in JavaScript & date-fns

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-fns

I'm working in NodeJS, which is currently running locally, but will later run somewhere else (a server of unknown location). I'm using the `date-fns` (2.14.0) and `date-fns-tz` (1.0.10) libraries. I am in the UK, and right now we are on BST (UTC+1).

I have dates stored in different databases/tables, the dates are saved in different time zones, and I am unable to change this, I have to work with them as I find them.

In this example I'll use 2 dates. I take some action which causes the dates to saved.

The UTC time right now is: 2020-09-18 10:57:00, BST: 2020-09-18 11:57:00. I'm rounding to the nearest minute for these examples.

1. TableA.Date = 2020-09-18 06:57:00
2. TableB.Date = 2020-09-18 10:57:00

So I can see that TableA.Date is saved in UTC-4 and TableB.Date is saved in UTC. I believe the UTC-4 is Eastern Daylight Time (EDT) - Boston, US, 'America/New_York' (IANA).

I would like to display all dates in UTC in my app, to provide users a consistent view, and the users will be viewing from all over the world.

Is this even possible..?

**Update**

I have this now:

```js
function test (dateStr, tz) {
  const toUtc = dateFnsTz.zonedTimeToUtc(dateStr, tz)
  const toZonedTime = dateFnsTz.utcToZonedTime(toUtc, 'UTC')
  const formatted = dateFnsTz.format(toZonedTime, 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'UTC')

  console.log(formatted)

  return null
}

test('2020-09-18 06:57:00', 'America/New_York') // 18 Sep 2020 10:57:00
test('2020-09-18 10:57:00', 'UTC')              // 18 Sep 2020 10:57:00
test('2020-09-18 11:57:00', 'Europe/London')    // 18 Sep 2020 10:57:00
```

Is this going to work consistently, or will this break daylight saving or anything else..?

Comment: Yes, it's possible provided you know the offset that is required to adjust the stored date to UTC. Hopefully a fixed offset has been used, otherwise you're likely to be at the mercy of daylight saving changes. BTW, the title of the question seems to be the opposite of what you want to do.

Comment: @RobG Thanks! I've added an update with some code. Does that look correct to you..? On the title, not sure what you mean, I want to display the date consistently, in UTC.

Comment: Your issue is parsing a timestamp using a particular location/timezone, the display part is  really secondary. Anyhow, the bit you've added is OK. I think date-fns-tz uses the same method as Luxon, both are based on support for [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat). The only issue I see is trying to parse a timestamp that doesn't exist or exists twice during daylight saving changeover in the specified location. But if the original was valid, that shouldn't occur.